# Could not find environment ScrapyEnvironment

Tags: scrapy, anaconda

I am trying to scrape a website using scrapy for which I am trying to run Spyder in Anaconda Navigator. For that, I have created an environment called `ScrapyEnvironment` and I am trying to activate the `ScrapyEnvironment` from command prompt. However the messege that is being shown here is that

```
Could not find conda environment: ScrapyEnvironment
You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info --envs`.
```

However, when I run the command `conda info --envs` in command prompt, it is displaying the conda environment as follows:

```
C:\Users\Android Dev5>conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
                         C:\Users\Android Dev5\Anaconda3New
                         C:\Users\Android Dev5\Anaconda3New\envs\ScrapyEnvironment
base                  *  C:\Users\Android Dev5\Miniconda3
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like the environment you're looking for was created by a different Anaconda install (i.e. you're using your Miniconda install, but the ScrapyEnv seems to have been created by Anaconda3New, judging by its location at least). I don't know how conda handles this situation. Have you tried activating the env from Anaconda3New base env?

Comment: What happens if you click the triangle to the right of `ScrapyEnvironment` in Navigator and select `Open Terminal`?

Comment: @orangeInk I don't think there's anything unusual about the base env being in a different location to user-created envs.

Comment: @nekomatic It's not so much about the location as it is about the Python that created that env. Based on the folder structure in the post, I'd guess that Anconda3New was used to create that env. However it also shows Miniconda3's base env as the currently active one, which might not be on the same Python version as Anaconda3New base env. The env was created with one conda installation and now they're trying to activate it with another. That might be a problem (*might be*, because I don't know).

Comment: @orangeInk OK I see your point - it looks like they have two different base envs.

Comment: @AnwesaRoy would it be a problem to just delete your `Miniconda3` installation and reinstall Anaconda at `Anaconda3New`, or vice versa?